# Update character index of word after preprocessing

Tags: python, json, character, offset

**How to update my character indexes after the change of a text??**

I'm doing an analysis on a text containing some stuff I want to remove (like URLs).

```py
original_text = "Hello <link> world"

def preprocess(text):
    text=strip_tags(text)
    text=remove_url(text)
    text=text.strip()
    text = re.sub(' +', ' ',text)
    return text

text = preprocess(original_text)
```

and after the preprocessing text is:

```
Hello world
```

Then I have my model which does some analysis automatically generating character indexes.

```py
output = mymodel.run_analysis(text)
```

and the output is something like this:

```json
{
    "text" : "Hello world",
    "analysis":
    [
        {
            "text": "Hello",
            "start_char": 0,
            "end_char": 5
        },
        {
            "text": "world",
            "start_char": 6,
            "end_char": 11
        }

    ]
}
```

But I would like to keep the original text too in the output with also the `start_char` and `end_char` which refer to the original text, like this:

```json
{
    "text" : "Hello world",
    "original_text" : "Hello <link> world",
    "analysis":
    [
        {
            "text": "Hello",
            "start_char": 0,
            "end_char": 5,
            "original_start_char": 0,
            "original_end_char": 5
        },
        {
            "text": "world",
            "start_char": 6,
            "end_char": 11,
            "original_start_char": 13,
            "original_end_char": 18
        }

    ]
}
```

How to do that? It could be good also to only have the offset to sum to the `start_char` and `end_char`: the important is to find the word in the original text.

I thought to do a for on each element of the analysis and running a regex on the `original_text` but is dangerous because I don't want to match an element with a substring contained for example in a URL (for example if `original_text = "Hello https://world.com world"`)

```py
def char_regex_ascii(word):
    return r"{}".format(re.escape(word))
my_regex = char_regex_ascii

for element in output["analysis"]:
    word = element["text"]
    r = re.compile(my_regex(word), flags=re.I | re.X | re.UNICODE)

    # for each matched token in sentence
    for m in r.finditer(original_text):
        ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Share the code snippet too which you have written please/

Comment: @Neeraj do you mean the code that generates this output? I have put a generic JSON output to make it more general, but the method adds `start_char` and `end_char` itself, while the preprocessing is a function which does a simple replace.

Comment: since You have not provided any code I can give You only the general direction of pretty much processing the text twice, once the whole one and then with filters and just append the results to the same dictionary. Your code and some part of the text file would be helpful

Comment: based on what I have seen: how about You run the text through analysis once without preprocessing and once with preprocess and then add the results together?

Comment: The problem is that there is the risk to have more results on the string before the preprocessing: I remove URLs because my analysis can find some wrong words in the middle of an URL and if I find the word `world` in a URL in the first analysis and in the second I don't find that word (because preprocessing removes URLs) I have a different number of elements and I can't match them